# Undefined reference despite netbeans showing function in code-completion

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

I am new to c++, but I got some programming experience in other programming languages, so it is no problem to read c++ code with a little googling.

For an uni project I need to write a game and we are supposed to use one of their libraries, called ACGL. We also use GLFW, which seems to work fine. (I copied the correct files of the GLFW-binaries to C:\MinGW\include and C:\MinGW\lib and added the .dll to the folder the main.cpp is located in)

I am using MinGW with Netbeans 8.0.1 for Windows 7 32-bit.
I downloaded ACGL and put the folders inside the include folder in C:\MinGW\include.

Now I have some code in my main.cpp:

```
//#define ACGL_OPENGL_VERSION_32
//#define ACGL_OPENGL_PROFILE_CORE
#include <ACGL/ACGL.hh>
//#include <ACGL/OpenGL/GL.hh>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window || !(ACGL::init(true))) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Essentially the GLFW example(which runs fine btw) with the ACGL include at top and the ACGL::init() function in the correct place.

Everything seems fine, and Netbeans is able to find  (Ctrl-Click) and it also finds the init function in the corresponding ACGL.cc (Ctrl-Click)

However when I try to compile the project with Netbeans the following error occurs:

```
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Tarek/Desktop/Netbeans Workspace/swpp-ws-14-15-a/MarbleGame'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/marblegame.exe
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Tarek/Desktop/Netbeans Workspace/swpp-ws-14-15-a/MarbleGame'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Tarek/Desktop/Netbeans Workspace/swpp-ws-14-15-a/MarbleGame'
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/marblegame.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Tarek/Desktop/Netbeans Workspace/swpp-ws-14-15-a/MarbleGame'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/marblegame build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -lglfw3dll -lopengl32
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Tarek\Desktop\Netbeans Workspace\swpp-ws-14-15-a\MarbleGame/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `ACGL::init(bool)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/marblegame.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Tarek/Desktop/Netbeans Workspace/swpp-ws-14-15-a/MarbleGame'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Tarek/Desktop/Netbeans Workspace/swpp-ws-14-15-a/MarbleGame'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

How can it be, that Netbeans finds the reference but the compiler doesn't?
I don't have any .a files to copy to C:\MinGW\lib so I don't know if I maybe have to link stuff another way for the compiler? The init function is defined in a namespace called "ACGL", but I call ACGL::init() so this can't be a problem either, right? What am I not seeing here?

If you need anything else (except for the code of ACGL - I don't think we're allowed to share that) please comment and I try to provide it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Netbeans finds the declaration but unlike with languages like C# or Java the declaration is separate from the implementation (which is in  a library and is not found at the link stage).

Comment: The error is probably related to your Makefile. The output you gave indicates that `ACGL` is not being compiled when you build and so the linker has nothing he can link when building the program (hence the error occurs)

Comment: Thanks for the quick advice, I think I understand what the problem is. I already know how to link libraries (like with GLFW and OpenGL), but I don't know how I can link something that is only present in the include folder of MinGW and doesn't have a .a-file in the lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had sources provided by my university and a CMakeLists.txt so I used cmake to generate a makefile for MSYS and recompiled with make which generates the object files and the library, which can be placed in C:\MinGW\lib.

Comment: Linkage was ok but the library I used before was erroneous.

Comment: Basically it's not a good idea to mix the MinGW with other libraries. You can tell NetBeans to use any other location for headers and libraries